# can't do curl on https url using php, WAMP server

Tags: php, api, curl, post, localhost

I'm trying to get data from this URL: https://www.fillip.co/?s=h2122

when I press on "F12" in Chrome I see that all info was come from this API url: https://www.fillip.co/process/api.php with this POST request:
{"action":"GetSimilarBids","bidid":2122}

I'm using this PHP code, that runs on localhost WAMP server:

```
echo getByAPI("GetSimilarBids", "2122");
function getByAPI($action, $numAdding = 0) {
    $postURL = 'https://www.fillip.co/process/api.php';
    switch($action) {
        case "GetSimilarBids":
            $postFields = array(
                "bidid " => $numAdding,
                "action" => $action
            );
            break;
    }
    
    $headers = [
    ':authority: www.fillip.co',
    ':method: POST',
    ':path: /process/api.php',
    ':scheme: https',
    'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5',
    'content-length: 40',
    'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'cookie: _ga=GA1.2.109987936.1635979165; intercom-id-tiiiwel8=8574341a-19f4-4486-8867-5eb75b8f4005; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; fillip_token=Mjc3MTI6NWY1NjZiM2Y4NDZhYjAzOGE0MjExNzVhNTYxM2RkMWQ1MzI3NTk5NjdkNTU3MGFmMDg1MWY1MTliYjVmNzE0Mg%3D%3D; jaco_referer=none; PHPSESSID=1oic090uf24bj6rh21qphhjnfq; fillip_guid=%7B14EAF76B-4C72-484B-B78D-1868CAFBD697%7D; _gid=GA1.2.1378140802.1643298373; intercom-session-tiiiwel8=M2wzb3JLYjRCZFpVL0RMNTJDTCtJTFdhd04wTFdyQTNDOURubnVLLzVHU0MzZ21FeStXcW5kYnhzQ1BBN1gwRS0tWUxub28rUmFuWEkwT2VmRXJjb3pUUT09--7016fd618c822fcb74e815828f40cfe2759b0de4',
    'dnt: 1',
    'origin: https://www.fillip.co',
    'referer: https://www.fillip.co/?s=h2122',
    'sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest: empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode: cors',
    'sec-fetch-site: same-origin',
    'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
    ];
    
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36';  // Setting useragent of a popular browser
    $cookie = 'cookie.txt';                                                     // Setting a cookie file to storecookie
    $ch = curl_init();                                                          // Initialising cURL session
    
    // Setting cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);                            // PreventcURL from verifying SSL certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);                            // Accept SSL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);                                // Script shouldfail silently on error
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);                              // Use cookies
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);                             // FollowLocation: headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);                             // Returningtransfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);                              // Settingcookiefile
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);                               // Settingcookiejar
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);                            // Settinguseragent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postURL);                                    // Setting URL to POSTto
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);                                       // Setting method as POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);                          // Setting POST fields as array
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT ,80);                                         // Setting cURL Port
    
    $results = var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));                                                 // Executing cURL session
    curl_close($ch);                                                            // Closing cURL session
    
    return $results;
}
```

And is the results:

```
array (size=37)
  'url' => string 'https://www.fillip.co/process/api.php' (length=37)
  'content_type' => null
  'http_code' => int 0
  'header_size' => int 0
  'request_size' => int 0
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 0
  'namelookup_time' => float 0
  'connect_time' => float 0
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0
  'size_upload' => float 0
  'size_download' => float 0
  'speed_download' => float 0
  'speed_upload' => float 0
  'download_content_length' => float -1
  'upload_content_length' => float -1
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string '' (length=0)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 0
  'local_ip' => string '' (length=0)
  'local_port' => int 0
  'http_version' => int 0
  'protocol' => int 0
  'ssl_verifyresult' => int 0
  'scheme' => string '' (length=0)
  'appconnect_time_us' => int 0
  'connect_time_us' => int 0
  'namelookup_time_us' => int 0
  'pretransfer_time_us' => int 0
  'redirect_time_us' => int 0
  'starttransfer_time_us' => int 0
  'total_time_us' => int 0
```

Comment: You never do `curl_exec` ?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I did, but it's not showing anything.

Comment: Please update your code with what exactly you're doing, including your `curl_exec` and how you access the data